# How to save a text files current line and prev line in a variable using Python?

Tags: python

Not sure if I'm trying to complete this task the best way but, I want to compare a current line and a previous line in the same text file to check if a new paragraph of text has begun. In my task, I need to know if the current line starts with "from", and if the previous line was a new line, then I need to stop saving the text in an array and start saving it in a new array.

Example:

> *some text saved in array1*
>
> (new line)
>
> From
>
> *new text need to be saved in array2*

I've posted my code as an idea of what I need to do.

```
with open(testEmail) as f:
        prevline = f.readLines()
        nextline = f.readlines()
        if line in prevline starts with"\n"
            if line in nextline starts with "From"
                //start saving in new array
        //save in array1
```

Is that possible in python?

Comment: You must be following the same (bad) tutorial as [this earlier question today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60421865/how-to-make-that-a-variable-with-readlines-read-the-second-line-of-a-txt-file). The answer is pretty much the same, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your logic is correct. But the issue with this implementation is that you're only checking the next line and no check is made with the previous line. For example, what if `nextline = \n` and `prevline = from`. For this case you may consider checking the condition as soon as prevline is read before reading into the nextline.

> use readline() instead of readlines()

The former reads only a single line whereas the latter would read all the contents in the file. For your case, the `readline()` would suffice.

```py
with open(testEmail) as f:
        prevline = f.readLine()
        if nextline in  ['\n', '\r\n']:
            if prevline == "From":
                //start saving in new array
        else:
           nextline = f.readline()
           if prevline in  ['\n', '\r\n']:
               if nextline == "From":
                //start saving in new array
           //save in array1
```

I hope you understand the logic here.

Comment: yes i understand! for my task i've omitted the what if (nextline = \n and prevline = from ) case. this has helped me tho thankyou